# Linking with GCC doesn't detect -fPIC flag

Tags: ld, multiboot

I am trying to link some files. Here is my command:

```
gcc -T linker.ld -o Stack\ Berry.bin -ffreestanding -O2 -nostlib kernel.o boot.o -fPIC -lgcc
```

How ever, I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: boot.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.multiboot' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
```

I have included the `-fPIC` argument, have I just put it in the wrong place? I haven't been able to find any thing for the syntax for this flag. Thanks!

Comment: The `-fPIC` option must be applied during the compile phase (the command that generates the object files) I think - rather than the link phase, as you are showing

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I tried it on compiling the GAS code (not a arg), and the command that generates the object file. It does not seem to work. `gcc -fPIC -c kernel.c -o kernel.o -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra`

Comment: (1) My first guess (and it is *only* a guess) was that it’s a command-line order problem. Have you tried changing the order of the command line? (2) Actually reading the “recompile with -fPIC” error make me doubt my first guess and believe that @steeldriver has the right idea. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) People will say that this question is off-topic here, and belongs on [SO]. I believe that it’s on-topic here, but I agree that it is likely to get answered more quickly and accurately on [SO]. If you don’t get an answer here, and the question doesn’t get migrated, I suggest that you flag it and ask to have it moved. Please don’t just repost the question.

Comment: Yes, I have tried changing the order.

Answer (score 0):

Your `boot.o` has a `.multiboot` elf section, which is incompatible with `-fPIC`. You can try to compile `boot.o` with `-fPIC` but that should fail.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html#OS-image-format for the header.

On the other hand, there's little sense in creating a bootable object with `-fPIC`. Even if there was a "dynamic loader", there can't be anything to dynamically link against during the boot process.

Comment: I could only find info on the header and the flag value, and it matched up with my boot.s. BTW the boot.o is an object file, non-compilable, as it should be boot.s.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by compiling/linking your .bin with -fPIC?